# Amazon ELB not loadbalancing between two servers

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I'm just set up a small load balanced architecture in AWS using two Large EC2 instances in the same availability zone with a non-sticky ELB in front.  Amazon reports that both instances are health and I see the healthchecks returning 200 on both servers, yet all traffic is being routed to one of the servers.  If I pull that server out of rotation traffic goes to the other server, but when I put it back in it all goes back to that one server.  This is live traffic - not a load test - so its not related to single-client-IP or sticky sessions.

Any suggestions for what I can look at or how to begin to debug the elastic load balancer setup?  Thanks

Comment: I'm going to assume your backends are (were as this is old) in different AZs and you had a limited set of clients which were caching DNS or you were using an A record for the ELB.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a stickiness policy for the ELB? Check in the AWS Console, EC2 > Load Balancers > [your ELB] > Description. Under Port Configuration it should say "Stickiness: Disabled".

Comment: Stickyness is no longer an option in AWS console...

Comment: I still see it is present in the documentation http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/US_StickySessions.html and in the AWS console.